# Who calls 'where' a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, parts-of-speech, intransitive-preposition

> **6 The fused relative construction**
>
> ▓ **Classification**
>  An initial illustration of the range of
>   constructions belonging to the fused relative category is given in
>   [1]:
>
> ```
> [1]         SIMPLE SERIES                        -EVERSERIES
>   i a. I spent what he gave me.         b. I spent whatever he gave me.
>  ii a. I gave him what money I had.     b. I gave him whatever money I had.
> iii a. I’ll go where you go.            b. I’ll go wherever you go.
> ```
>
> On one dimension we have a contrast between the simple series and the
>   -ever series, the latter being marked by a relative word ending in -ever. Cutting across this is the major category contrast: the fused relatives are NPs in [i-ii], PPs in [iii]. And within the NP category
>   we have a further distinction according as the relative word is a
>   pronoun, as in [i], or a determinative, as in [ii]. (CGEL,p.1068)

Considering that they are calling *before* in this sentence, *I saw him before he left*, a preposition (p.58), I can tell why they are calling the clause, *where you go*: in [iii], prepositional. What I want to know, now, is, if there are any persons other than the CGEL’s writers who call this *where* usage a preposition. Are there any others?

Comment: You say "They are calling the clause .... in [iii] prepositional". Where do they say it is prepositional?

Comment: @fluffy *PPs* is an abbreviation for *preposition[al phrase]s*. It can be found in the middle of the explanation after the table: *Cutting across this is ... PPs in [iii].*

Comment: Oh I saw it. But then, "where" is not a preposition, it behaves as a prepositional phrase because the meaning is "to the place where you go", right?

Comment: CGEL doesn't call *where* a *preposition* but a *PP*, which is what it 'stands for', just as they call *what* an NP, because that it is what it stands for.

Comment: The 2002 *CGEL* considers "where" to be a preposition, and considers the expression "where you go" in [1.a.iii] to be a preposition phrase. On page 1050 fn 6, the authors of *CGEL* explain that traditional grammars classify "where" as an adverb.

Comment: @F.E.: Thank you; that is informative, and I retract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer you one respectable grammarian who follows this usage: Bas Aarts, in the *Oxford Modern English Grammar*.

At **3.7 Prepositions and prepositional  phrases**, **Table 3.19 Prepositions** he marks *when* with the sign ‘<sup>intr</sup>’, which he glosses “Prepositions marked <sup>’intr’</sup> do not take a Complement”. The context is a discussion of *transitive* and *intransitive prepositions*; Aarts defines intransitive prepositions as those which “can stand **on their own** as Heads of prepositional phrases which typically function as verbal Complements” [my emphasis].

However, he does not give an example of such an intransitive use of *where*, and I suspect he intends the <sup>intr</sup> in a sense which anticipates **5.5.1.5 Clauses functioning as Complement in prepositional phrases** and **Table 5.14  English conjunctive prepositions**: there he includes *where* among those “conjunctive prepositions” which take only clauses, not NPs, as Complement.

At **7.3.3.5 Free relative clauses** he gives

> **103** However, you can move your money [*when* you like] ...

among  examples of free relative clauses headed by  *free relative conjunctive prepositions*, arguing that

> the bracketed strings can be paraphrased, though not always equally easily, by a Head noun + relative clause structure. Thus (103) can be paraphrased as in (107).
>
> > **107** You can move your money at a **time** [<sub>clause</sub>*when you like*].

Comment: I have Bas Aart’s ‘English Syntax and argumentation’ Korean Version. After reading your answer, I've leafed through it again. The book is translated and I’m poor in English, it would not be delivered well, but this is what I can abbreviate it as: (1) He calls relative clauses, both non-restrictive and restrictive, adjuncts. (2) So if ‘that’ leads a complement clause, he calls it complementizer; it ‘that’ leads a adjunct, adjunctizer.

Comment: . (3) Recently, there are assertions that all the adjuncts needs to be sorted into prepositions, and it is to be welcomed by him: even in both ‘They live ‘there’’, ‘He won’t live ‘now’’, there and now are prepositions. (4) None of analyses could be final, and they would not agree what a person arrived at. Consequently for seeking best analysis itself would be encouraged.